# PowerShell: Get-User –OrganizationalUnit One Level?

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm trying to get ONE LEVEL of the command Get-User –OrganizationalUnit.

```
Get-User –OrganizationalUnit "domain.local/ou/this-one"
```

This returns the this-one ou and everything under it, I want a one level return, what paramteres am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array based on distinguished property :

```
$aduserinfo = get-aduser -Identity "Username here"
$ou = $aduserinfo.distinguishedname.split(",")[2]
$ou = $ou.substring(3)
```

Play around With the index [2] and you will get the OU you search for.
`Substring` removes the 3 first characters "ou=" in the index.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific parameter for doing this, how about using a filter?

Like this:

```
Get-User -Filter "distinguishedName -like 'CN=*,OU=This-one,OU=OU,DC=domain,DC=local'"
```

Failing that the get-aduser cmd-let allows you to set the scope of the search like this:

```
get-aduser -searchbase "OU=This-one,OU=OU,DC=domain,DC=local" -searchscope 1
```

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx

regards
Arcass

Comment: Just checked the docs, -searchbase needed to be given as a DN. Example updated.

Comment: i don't get any results, when I remove the -searchscope it works (however all the ous underneath are also included)

Comment: I just found out the answer, I read the documentation and instead of "-searchscope Base", you are to use "-searchscope 1", thank you for getting me on the right trail mate!

Comment: Update! It does not work as I wish to use this through Exchange Console. So i need a "Get-User –OrganizationalUnit "domain.local/ou/this-one"" solution :/

Comment: Can you import the active directory module into the Exchange Console:
   import-module activedirectory
Failing that have you tried the -filter parameter (example above) on the get-user cmd-let?

Comment: Yes have tried doing it via that way, I get the error: "Enable-Mailbox : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and
 its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you aren't still looking for an answer here, but for anyone with the same problem try using:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Searchbase "OU=OUYouareSearching,DC=domain,DC=net" -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter *
```

**-SearchScope OneLevel** is the key here.